How to show a Right click context menu on Gtk4?
I am trying to create a context menu, which will show in the Gtk4 window on mouse right click. In case of Gtk3 i used gtk_menu_popup_at_pointer(GTK_MENU(popup), event) function  to show context menu, but this function is removed from gtk4. In Gtk4 How can this be done?
I tried it this way, but it is showing ---
Gtk-WARNING **: 08:37:09.566: Finalizing GtkApplicationWindow 0x563d9f0da290, but it still has children left: massage! check this script ---
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void create_window ( GtkApplication *application );
static void quit   ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data );
static void msg   ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data );

static void
click_pos_on_button_release (GtkGesture *click,
                               int n_press,
                               gdouble x,
                               gdouble y,
                               gpointer user_data)
{
    GdkEventSequence *sequence = gtk_gesture_single_get_current_sequence (
            GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE (click));
    GdkEvent *event = gtk_gesture_get_last_event (click, sequence);
    g_print ("%f  %f\n", x, y);

         GdkRectangle rectangle;
         rectangle.x = x;
         rectangle.y = y;
         rectangle.width = 1;
         rectangle.height = 1;
         
         gtk_popover_set_pointing_to (GTK_POPOVER (user_data), &rectangle);

         gtk_popover_popup (GTK_POPOVER (user_data));
    
    gtk_gesture_set_sequence_state (GTK_GESTURE (click), sequence,
                                    GTK_EVENT_SEQUENCE_CLAIMED);
}


int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    GtkApplication *application;
    int status;

    /// ***
    application = gtk_application_new ( "gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_signal_connect_swapped ( application, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( create_window ), application );

    /// ***
    status = g_application_run ( G_APPLICATION ( application ), argc, argv );
    g_object_unref ( application );

    return status;
}

void create_window ( GtkApplication *application )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GMenu *menubar;
    GMenu *menu;
    GMenuItem *close_item, *pref_menu_item;

    /// ***
    window = gtk_application_window_new ( application );
    gtk_window_set_application ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), application );

    /// ***
    const GActionEntry entries[] =
    {
        {"close", quit, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 } },
        {"Preferences", msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 0, 0 } } 
    };

    /// **
    g_action_map_add_action_entries ( G_ACTION_MAP ( application ), entries, G_N_ELEMENTS ( entries ), NULL );

    /// ***
    menubar = g_menu_new();
    menu    = g_menu_new();
    close_item    = g_menu_item_new ( "Close", "app.close" );
    pref_menu_item = g_menu_item_new("Preferences", "app.Preferences");


    /// *** add item on menu
    g_menu_append_item ( menu, close_item );
    g_menu_append_item ( menu, pref_menu_item );
    g_object_unref ( close_item );
    g_object_unref ( pref_menu_item );


    /// ***
    g_menu_append_submenu ( menubar, "File", G_MENU_MODEL ( menu ) );
    g_object_unref ( menu );

    /// ***
    gtk_application_set_menubar ( application, G_MENU_MODEL ( menubar ) );
    gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar ( GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW ( window ), FALSE );


    GMenuModel *model;
    model = G_MENU_MODEL(menu);

    GtkWidget *popover = gtk_popover_menu_new_from_model_full (G_MENU_MODEL (model), GTK_POPOVER_MENU_NESTED);
    gtk_popover_set_autohide (GTK_POPOVER (popover), TRUE);  
    gtk_popover_set_has_arrow (GTK_POPOVER (popover), FALSE);

    gtk_widget_set_parent (popover, window);

        GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
        gtk_gesture_single_set_button (GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE (gesture), GDK_BUTTON_SECONDARY);
        GtkEventController *controller = GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture);
        g_signal_connect (controller, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_pos_on_button_release), popover);
        gtk_widget_add_controller (window, controller);

    /// ***
    gtk_window_present ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ) );
}

static void quit ( GSimpleAction *action, G_GNUC_UNUSED GVariant *parameter, G_GNUC_UNUSED gpointer data )
{
    g_print ( "You choose `%s` action\n", g_action_get_name ( G_ACTION( action ) ) );
}

static void msg ( GSimpleAction *action, G_GNUC_UNUSED GVariant *parameter, G_GNUC_UNUSED gpointer data )
{
    g_print ( "You choose `%s` action\n", g_action_get_name ( G_ACTION( action ) ) );
}

How can it be made error free?
*Thanks in advance to the answerers.

I have already answered the question about the possibilities of a pop-up menu here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78261881/22768315
Here is an example of how to bind a pop-up menu to a GtkBox.

#pragma once
#include"class-my-box.h"

struct _MyBox
{
  GtkBox parent_instance;
  GtkWidget *menu;
};
 
struct _MyBoxClass
{
  GtkBoxClass parent_class;
};
 
G_DEFINE_TYPE (MyBox, my_box, GTK_TYPE_BOX)

static void
cp_pressed(GtkGestureClick *gesture,int, double x, double y, gpointer * self)
{
    gtk_popover_set_pointing_to(GTK_POPOVER(MY_BOX(self)->menu), 
                    &(const GdkRectangle){x,y,1,1});

    gtk_popover_popup(GTK_POPOVER (MY_BOX(self)->menu));
}

static void
item1_cb() 
{
    g_print("item1\n");
}

static void
item2_cb()
{
    g_print("item2\n");
}


static void
my_box_init(MyBox *self)
{

}
 
static void
my_box_dispose(GObject *object)
{
     while (gtk_widget_get_first_child(GTK_WIDGET(object)) != NULL)
     {
     gtk_widget_unparent(gtk_widget_get_first_child(GTK_WIDGET(object)));
     } 
}

// allocate a size for the popover by calling
static void
my_box_size_allocate (GtkWidget *widget,
             int        width,
             int        height,
             int        baseline)
{
    MyBox *self = MY_BOX (widget);

    gtk_popover_present (GTK_POPOVER (self->menu));
}

static void
my_box_map(GtkWidget *widget)
{
    MyBox *self = MY_BOX(widget);
    // GMenu (model)
    GMenu *menu = g_menu_new();
    GMenuItem *menu_item_item1 = g_menu_item_new("Item1", "spot.item1");
    GMenuItem *menu_item_item2 = g_menu_item_new("Item2", "spot.item2");
    g_menu_append_item(menu, menu_item_item1);
    g_menu_append_item(menu, menu_item_item2);
    g_object_unref(menu_item_item1);
    g_object_unref(menu_item_item2);
    // popover menu
    self->menu = gtk_popover_menu_new_from_model_full (G_MENU_MODEL(menu),GTK_POPOVER_MENU_NESTED);
    gtk_widget_set_parent(self->menu,GTK_WIDGET(self));
    // left mouse button
    GtkGesture *gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button (GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture),3);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(GTK_WIDGET(self),GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture));

    g_signal_connect(gesture,"pressed",G_CALLBACK(cp_pressed),self);

    GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(my_box_parent_class)->map(widget);
    
}
static void
my_box_class_init (MyBoxClass *class)
{
 
  GObjectClass *object_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (class);
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (class);
 
  object_class->dispose = my_box_dispose;
  widget_class->size_allocate = my_box_size_allocate;
  widget_class->map = my_box_map;

  // Actions
  gtk_widget_class_install_action(widget_class, "spot.item1", NULL,item1_cb);
  gtk_widget_class_install_action(widget_class, "spot.item2", NULL,item2_cb);
}
 
GtkWidget *
my_box_new (GtkOrientation orientation, int spacing)
{
  MyBox *self = g_object_new (MY_TYPE_BOX,NULL);
  gtk_box_set_spacing(GTK_BOX(self),spacing);   
  gtk_orientable_set_orientation(GTK_ORIENTABLE(self), orientation);
          
  return GTK_WIDGET(self); 
 }


Supplement:
gtk_widget_child_focus: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

As far as I know, the specified error message is a problem of GTK4.
However, it only occurs if no child has been assigned to a window.
So you could improve the situation if you add a label to the window.
Then this error will only occur when your program is terminated.
Finalizing GtkApplicationWindow 0x60f22390f4e0, but it still has children left:
   - GtkPopoverMenu 0x60f2239075b0

This is then due to the fact that a popover-menu is not considered as a correct child, where such as a label. Therefore it is not automatically finalized.
In order to program an error-free popup menu, it is therefore necessary to derive your own class from a GtkWidget and implement the popup menu. To do this, it must then be finalised there.
My example shows how it works.
Greetings

It seems too complicated. It would have been better to just provide the right click context menu script.
